# How did The Doctor and Clara escape his timeline?

Tags: doctor-who, continuity

In the last episode of season 7, The Doctor goes into his timeline to save Clara. It ends when they see his war regeneration and Clara faints. Did I miss a special episode between that one and the 50th anniversary special? Because they never explained how they escaped his timeline.

Comment: Not a real answer, but note that the trailer for the 2013 Christmas special mentions Trenzalore, so it seems as if we will return there then.

Comment: Probably after having read the idea somewhere, I did think that maybe they haven’t escaped his timestream yet — that the adventure we saw in the 50th anniversary special occurred prior to the 12th Doctor visiting Trenzalore. However, as he mentions visiting Trenzalore near the end of the special, I don’t think that theory works.

Comment: He waved his Sonic Screwdriver, of course..

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, the Doctor led her out. He was shown to be immune to the scattering effect that the Great Intelligence and Clara experienced, and it is his own personal time-tunnel, so one would assume that it would be familiar to him.

Before entering the timestream, the Doctor says to Vastra, Jenny, and Strax, “If I don't make it back, and I might not…,” which implies that there is only a chance that he will not return (which is referring to the possibility of the timestream collapsing in on itself as a result of the paradoxes caused by him being in it).

Comment: I think you’re spot on. At the end of *The Name of the Doctor*, when they see the War Doctor, The Doctor says to Clara something along the lines of “Come on, we need to get back.” I’m pretty sure the implication is that he subsequently got them out of the time stream. It could have been clearer, but the main focus of that scene was **OMG LOOK A HITHERTO-UNKNOWN PRIOR VERSION OF THE DOCTOR PLAYED BY THAT GUY FROM ALIEN, GOOD GOLLY GUMDROPS** (which is my personal catchphrase suggestion for Peter Capaldi’s Doctor).

Comment: I have long been asking myself this question but I think his timeline isn’t collapsing. As I can see it, him inside his own timeline it’s just him. I’m getting closer to this ep to rewatch it, so I may be wrong.